# Nativescript Vue: How to create a basic layout

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How can I create a basic template for all my pages?

I try to make a RadSideDrawer on all pages available. (With exception for some specific pages like login / registration etc.).

Currently I copy and past my Menu on all pages. What is the correct way handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown any code... So not sure how are you even including it. In app-root?

But you can set menu to false to disable it on some pages:

Example:

```
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer'

 let sideDrawer = Application.getRootView()
  sideDrawer.getViewById('sideDrawer')
  sideDrawer.gesturesEnabled  = false
```

And enable it programmatically this way.

Comment: I think I misunderstand the concept of the nativescript menu. I always tried to load a new page on clicking an element. Instead I should have only one page with different components loaded on a click like here. https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Evc8t6&v=4. Is this correct now?

Comment: @PhilippS.  NO, NS has different concept recommended then Vue's SPA. Every page is for itself and menu is on all of them: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-drawer-navigation-vue/app/components Also see NS core example how they do it: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/tree/master/packages/template-drawer-navigation/app They made menu as root that is available on all other pages, simple as that. And pages are pages not components to share around.